# Issue with scrolling down to scrape Google Reviews

Tags: r, rvest, rselenium

I am trying scrape data from Google Reviews (stars, commentary, date, etc.).

I tried to adapt a code that I found available online but am having problems to make it work. Apparently, R is not managing to scroll down google reviews and only returns the first ten reviews (that are the ones that Google displays without scrolling)

Has someone came across the same issue? Thanks!

```
#install.packages("rvest")
#install.packages("xml2")
#install.packages("RSelenium")

library(rvest)
library(xml2)
library(RSelenium)

rmDr=rsDriver(port = 4444L, browser=c("firefox"))
myclient= rmDr$client
myclient$navigate("https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=emporio+santa+maria#lrd=0x94ce576a4e45ed99:0xa36a342d3ceb06c3,1,,,")
#click on the snippet to switch focus----------
webEle <- myclient$findElement(using = "css",value = ".review-snippet")
webEle$clickElement()
#simulate scroll down for several times-------------

scroll_down_times=1000
for(i in 1 :scroll_down_times){
  webEle$sendKeysToActiveElement(sendKeys = list(key="page_down"))
  #the content needs time to load,wait 1 second every 5 scroll downs
  if(i%%5==0){
    Sys.sleep(3)
  }
}

#loop and simulate clicking on all "click on more" elements-------------
webEles <- myclient$findElements(using = "css",value = ".review-more-link")
for(webEle in webEles){
  tryCatch(webEle$clickElement(),error=function(e){print(e)}) # trycatch to prevent any error from stopping the loop
}
pagesource= myclient$getPageSource()[[1]]
#this should get you the full review, including translation and original text-------------
reviews=read_html(pagesource) %>%
  html_nodes(".review-full-text") %>%
  html_text()

#number of stars
stars <- read_html(pagesource) %>%
  html_node(".review-dialog-list") %>%
  html_nodes("g-review-stars > span") %>%
  html_attr("aria-label")


#time posted
post_time <- read_html(pagesource) %>%
  html_node(".review-dialog-list") %>%
  html_nodes(".dehysf") %>%
  html_text()`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The codes are all correct, but you didn't target the correct element, use `.review-dialog-list` in css instead. That element is where the scroll bar resides.

```r
library(RSelenium)

rmDr <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox")
driver <- rmDr$client
driver$navigate("https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=emporio+santa+maria#lrd=0x94ce576a4e45ed99:0xa36a342d3ceb06c3,1,,,")

 Sys.sleep(3) # wait a couple of seconds to let browser render the review window.

webEle <- driver$findElement(using = "css",value = ".review-dialog-list")

for(i in 1 : 5){
    webEle$sendKeysToElement(sendKeys = list(key = "page_down"))
    Sys.sleep(1)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Yifu. unfortuantely i got the following error: Selenium message:Unable to locate element: .review-dialog-list

Comment: After you navigate to that page, you may need to wait a couple of seconds for the review window to appear. Can can add a `Sys.sleep()` after that line.

Comment: Thanks, Yifu. Got the following error on running the code, after some scroll downs. Do you know whats up?: 
> webEles <- myclient$findElements(using = "css",value = ".review-more-link")
Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 4444: Connection refused

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what it is. Possibly, you could avoid it by reducing the frequency or speed of scrolling down. And you should use `findElement` instead of `findElements`.